# Django url pattern not registering

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a custom Django app `myapp` with a `urls.py` like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^data/(?P<name>.+)$',
        'myapp.views.serve',
        name='myapp_getdata'),
)
```

I've confirmed that `myapp` is registered and is showing up in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`. However, when I try to do:

```
reverse("myapp_getdata", args=('some/arbitrary/path_-_with_varying_characters.extension',))
```

I get a NoReverseMatch error. Why is this?

Comment: The urls.py is inside the app? or at the project level?

Comment: Post your project's urls.py plz

Comment: Are you sure your pattern matches the url?

Comment: did you include the app.urls into the site.urls (ROOT_URLCONF)?

Answer (score 1):

By defining `(?P<name>.+)` in your URL, you're defining a kwarg called `name`. Try it with a kwarg;

```
reverse("myapp_getdata", kwargs={
    'name': 'some/arbitrary/path_-_with_varying_characters.extension'
})
```